# Dynamically Passing Table Names - using SQL Command from Variable

Tags: variables, ssis, foreach-loop-container

I read this thread: [SSIS : Dynamically passing Table names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27673789/ssis-dynamically-passing-table-names) and this is exactly what I'm trying to achieve. I got to the point of creating the string variable.

However, in the OLEdb source editor, when I chose to use SQL Command from Variable, the preview gave the following error prompt:

Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0202009
Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB Source [37]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E14.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E14  Description: "Statement(s) could not be prepared.".
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E14  Description: "Must declare the table variable "@".".

Appreciate some help on what could be the issue here.

Below are the components that I have set up.

EXECUTE SQL TASK:

> SELECT name from sys.tables WHERE name like'%$Company Information'Order by name
>   Result Set: Variable Name = User::IndivTableName; Result Name = 0; Data Type=Object

For Each Loop Container:

> Enumerator: Foreach ADO Enumerator
>
> ADO Object source variable: User::IndivTableName
>
> Enumeration mode: Rows in the first table
>
> (Is this needed?) Variable mappings: Variable = User::IndivTable; Index=0; Data Type = Object

String Variable:

> Variable Name: User::CompanyInformation
>
> Expression: 
>   "select [name],[address],[address 2],[city],[phone no_],[fax no_],
>   [VAT Registration no_],[registration no_],[business type] from " + "@[User::IndivTableName] "
>
> Evaluated Value: 
>   select [name],[address],[address 2],[city],[phone no_],[fax no_],
>   [VAT Registration no_],[registration no_],[business type] from @[User::IndivTableName]

Data Source Editor:

> Data Access Mode: SQL command from variable
>
> Variable Name: User::CompanyInformation
>
> Variable Value: 
>   select [name],[address],[address 2],[city],[phone no_],[fax no_],
>   [VAT Registration no_],[registration no_],[business type] from @[User::IndivTableName]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable mappings at *ForEach ADO Enumerator* are mandatory, your mappings are ok. Please change datatype of User::IndivTable variable to string.

Change Variable 'User::CompanyInformation' expression to

```
"select [name],[address],[address 2],[city],[phone no_],[fax no_],  
[VAT Registration no_],[registration no_],[business type] from " + [User::IndivTable]
```

Variable *User::IndivTableName* contains DataTable, so it cannot be used in expression. You iterate over it and store the first column into *User::IndivTable* variable.

Comment: Hi, I changed the datatype of User::IndivTable to String and also updated the User::CompanyInformation expression as advised, but it still prompts the same error. Do I need to set up a value or expression against this IndivTable variable?

Comment: @JamieLim, can you set up a breakpoint on DataFlow, check value of the *User::CompanyInformation* and put it here.

Comment: Hi @Ferdipux, I managed to sort this out.  User::IndivTable set up with Datatype= String and Value= the first result from the Execute SQL Task. The final expression I used for User::CompanyInformation is: "SELECT [name],[address],[address 2],[city],[phone no_],[fax no_],  
[VAT Registration no_],[registration no_],[business type] FROM" + "[" +@IndivTable + "]"